# Typescript (Angular2) generic constructor factory

Tags: angular, generics, typescript

Im using typescipt 2.
Im writing some parser method which receives a model from the server and converts it to an instance I can use.

Code:

```
export interface Constructable {
     copy(other : any) : void;
}

//in my Convert class which converts server responses to model
private static _parseT<T extends Constructable>(obj : any) : T {
    let instance = Object.create(T); // the row of the compile-time error
    instance.constructor.apply(instance);
    instance.copy(obj);
    return instance;
}
```

and lets assume I have the following class

```
export class Foo implements  Constructable {
    private test : string  = null;

    public copy(other:any) : void {
        this.test = other.test;
    }
}
```

I have a compile time error

> Could not find name T

now, Im sure its not the syntax but I couldn't find how.

To clear things out. this is how the useage looks like:

```
public static ParseFoo(data: any) : Foo{
    return Convert._parseT<Foo>(data.mResult); // data is a server response object
}
```

**NOTE**

Although some factory pattern would solve this, I would really like to stay with the `Copy` method instead of some `Generate` which creates and returns an instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because `T` is a type, not a `class`.

A `class` in typescript has this signature: `new(...args: any[]) => any` and you can call Object.create on it, since `T` isn't a variable in your function you can't do such a thing.

To achieve what you want to do, you have to pass the `class` itself as argument:

```
private static _parseT<T extends Constructable>(clazz: new(...args: any[]) => any, obj : any) : T {
    let instance = <Constructable>new clazz();
    instance.copy(obj);
    return <T>instance;
}
```

This way, the only `clazz` that will be accepted is the one that constructs your type.

You can have an example on something I made recently on [github](https://github.com/noe-fc/api/blob/master/src/core/injector.ts#L15) (not an angular project but your issue is a pure typescript issue).

An example call for this function:

```
let FooInstance = this._parseT<FooClass>(FooClass, myObj);
```

Here, the first `FooClass` is the type, while the seconde one reefers to the `class` itself.

Since you can't get the class of a type at runtime, it's the only olution for you to construct a class from its type.

Comment: its synatictically incorrect.  clazz:new(...args:any[]):T is wrong.
tried to convert it to clazz:new(...args:any[])=>T and then I have compile errors as well

Comment: oh yes sorry I'll fix this typo, but the second one should compile... oO (check the example I linked, it compiles perfectly)

Comment: Property 'copy' does not exist on type 'new (...args: any[]) => T'

Also

Type 'new (...args: any[]) => T' is not assignable to type T

Comment: Oh yes, that's because I created an implementation without knowing what you wanted to achieve, if I'm right you want to create an instance from an object and its class, with properties already set? EDIT: I think you have to change `=>T` for `=>any` because the `T` returned by new doesn't have the copy method, I'll change the response a bit to fit this.

Comment: yes. but I always want to create the object via the empty ctor and then just invoke the copy method.

Comment: In fact, you don't even have to use Object.create, you can simply call the method's constructor if you want to create the object itself. As the objects you'll manage using this method should be models, their constructors should be either empty or pure property-bindign constructors, then this will work like a charm.

Comment: return <T>instance; otherwise youre trying to return Construct instead of T.
Ill check in minutes. have some battery problems atm. it complies tho